# Rake command using the wrong path

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Recently I installed jruby and put it in my home directory. This apparently hijacked rake:

```
$ which ruby
/usr/bin/ruby
$ which rake
/home/user/jruby-1.5.5/bin/rake
```

Which seemed to be causing problems. So I moved the jruby folder and reinstalled rake, which at first seemed to fix it:

```
$ which rake
/usr/bin/rake
```

But when I run rake it's still trying to use the one in jruby:

```
user@user-desktop:~/rails/appname$ rake db:migrate
bash: /home/user/jruby-1.5.5/bin/rake: No such file or directory
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [RVM](http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/rvm/install/). It is invaluable for isolating different Ruby versions. Once installed do

```
rvm install jruby
```

That gets you a separate environment for running JRuby. You can switch between versions with

```
rvm system
rvm jruby
```